# How to synchronize iphone paid-to-free price change with app version change?

Tags: iphone, release, in-app-purchase

I have a paid app at the App Store. I want to convert this app to a free app that offers some content with in-app purchase that the paid app used to contain. How do I ensure that the price change happens at the same time as the version change (that includes the in-app functionality)?

I know that I can specify both the date for version release and the date for price change but if they don't happen at the same time, I'll end up with customers that either:

1) Get the new version and have to pay for it and then pay even more when unlocking features with in-app purchase

or

2) Get the old version for free and don't have to pay for anything since the old version doesn't have in-app purchase for the features. Then people who don't get all for free will be sad and say "how come he got all for free and I have to pay for the same features?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably just have to monitor the approval process. Take notice when the app goes into review and set the app to be free a day or two after. Otherwise, you are basically taking a shot in the dark unfortunately.

There are several things I wish that Apple would do differently with App Submission, this is now also added to my list.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a better way. Set you update to 'developer release'. Then when it's passed review, release it. It will change status to 'Processing for App Store'. Go in to the Rights and Pricing menu and set the availability date to some time in the future, so you're app is no longer available. Then, when the update changes state to 'Ready for Sale' go back in to Rights and Pricing, set the price tier to Free and make it available any time in the past. That way there's no risk of anyone getting screwed over.

If you download the iTunes Connect app, you'll also get a message when the update changes status from 'Processing for App Store' to 'Ready for Sale'. Easy :)